# An implicit function is not sufficient to allow the use of implicit differentiation?

Tags: calculus, implicit-differentiation, implicit-function-theorem

$x,y \in \mathbb{R}$ and $F: D\subset \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ where

$$ F =\sqrt{x^2 - y^2} + \arccos\Big(\frac{x}{y}\Big) = 0 \tag{1}$$

Noticing that the square-root and inverse cosine functions only return positive or $0$ values, the only way for this statement to work is if both output $0$. Therefore $(1)$ defines an implicit function $y = g(x) = x$ excluding the point $(0,0)$. Unfortunately, you cannot conclude that $(1)$ implies an implicit function from the implicit function theorem. Consider the point $(2,2)$. We apply the implicit function theorem around this point. The partial derivatives $F_x$ and $F_y$ evaluated at $(2,2)$ or any point $(x, y=x)$ where $F(x,y) = 0$ is undefined and so we cannot use the theorem, which only gives a sufficient condition for the existence of an implicit function. So when it doesn't apply, who knows if a function exists. In this case, we were able to find one.

If the implicit function theorem holds for a function $F$, guaranteeing the existence of some function, we can apply implicit differentiation to the equation. If the implicit function theorem doesn't hold, but we know an implicit function exists, you'd think (or maybe hope) 'well the function exists so I might as well try implicit differentiation.' In $(1)$, we know that $g'(x) = 1$. Yet, implicit differentiation gives you junk (you get a square-root in the denominator). How can an implicit function $y(x)$ exist but implicit differentiation not work? Differentiation is just a operation. If you have an object to work on, shouldn't differentiation give something reasonable when the object is reasonable? $(1)$ must be much different than $y = x$ excluding the origin

Comment: So, $F$ is a number? And what is $D$? An arbitrary set?

Comment: $F$ I try to denote as a function set equal to $0$. $D$ is the domain of the function where $y \neq 0$, $|x| \leq |y|$, and $x^2 - y^2 \geq 0$

Comment: So, for $(x,y)\in D$ you have $|x|\le|y|$ and $|x|\ge|y|$. Thus, $D = \{(x,y) : |x|=|y|\}$. So, your $D$ is just a union of two lines?

Comment: Yeah the union of the two 45 degree lines excluding the origin. Kind of interesting visualizing the surface above this domain. I can see why the partial derivatives $F_x$ and $F_y$ would be undefined. You can't even move in the $x$ direction of the domain so $F_x$ wouldn't be defined. You have to move along the line, which is at an angle

Comment: Then of course the implicit function theorem cannot be used here because it requires an open domain. I don't exactly get your question. In this particular case, sure, you have a 1-dimensional manifold on which the function is defined and an implicit function whose graph is exactly this manifold. And yes, you can incidently differentiate it because the manifold is differentiable. So, what's the question?

Comment: Why doesn't implicit differentiation give the correct result of 1? I'm under the impression that the implicit function theorem is used to establish the existence of a function, and not to establish the use of implicit differentiation

Comment: Have you read my comment? Here, $F_x$ and $F_y$ don't exist.

Comment: Again, $F_x$ and $F_y$ don't exist. How would you invoke implicit differentiation if the conditions are not met at all?

Comment: Ok I think I'm starting to understand. In this case, I just have to rewrite $(1)$ as $y = x$ excluding the origin and differentiate it. It can't be done any other way. That's kind of interesting. Messing around with the form of a function can sometimes prevent you from doing certain things

Comment: "It can't be done any other way." That's correct. Your question becomes more interesting though if you replace $x^2-y^2$ under the square root by $y^2-x^2$ and let $D := \{(x,y) : |x|\le|y|,\,y\neq 0\}$. Then still the implicit function theorem cannot be invoked because your manifold $\{(x,\pm x)\}$ is the boundary of $D$. However, $F_x$ and $F_y$ exist in the interior of $D$ and $-F_x/F_y$ tends to the "correct" value $1$ on the boundary.

Comment: You comments have helped me out a lot, thank you

Comment: You're welcome!